# Узнать количество доступных потоков на Си

Tags: c, opencl, parallel

Пишу функцию на `C` с помощью библиотеке OpenCL. Как я понимаю, я говорю программе, чтобы она данную функцию выполняла на видеокарте. Соответственно, всё программирование тоже самое, просто если я буду параллельность добавлять, то я могу указать не 8 потоков ( 8 ядер ), а сколько видеокарта позволит. Как можно мне узнать, сколько доступно потоков в самой функции? Что прописать?

Comment: А в описании библиотеки этого нету? А какую именно ф-цию из OpenGL вы используете?

Comment: Если я не путаю, можно указать число потоков 0 и OpenCL сам все сделает. Причем производительность будет чуть ли не выше, чем если указывать число руками.

Comment: @nick_n_a я еще слишком мало знаю, библиотеку пока не трогал, нашел лишь пример запуска функции на видеокарте

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов хорошо, посмотрю эту версию. Но везде по-моему говорят, что нужно указывать число потоков)

Comment: @Fresto Задавайте вопросы про конкретные функции OpenCL - тогда можно будет точнее сказать :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов хм, так я не про функции хотел спросить. Вот я написал функцию свою на Си, указал, чтобы эту функцию обрабатывала видеокарта. Всё окей. Но если мне на Си нужно будет конкретную функцию распараллелить, То я должен уже в самой Си прописывать параллельность, используя все потоки, которые у меня есть в наличие. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: @Fresto "указал, чтобы эту функцию обрабатывала видеокарта." - и как вы это сделали? Сказали вслух "ну пожаалуйста!"? OpenCL - набор функций, через которые происходит управление исполнением.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов я использовал готовый пример. С помощью функции enqueueReadBuffer(memBuf, GL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(buf), buf)

Comment: @Fresto начните с чтения документации. enqueueReadBuffer не вызывает исполнения ядра. Исполнение - clEnqueueNDRangeKernel и там параметр local_work_size. Если там ноль - OpenCL сам принимает решение во сколько потоков и как запускать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не читал документацию на английском прежде, видимо нужно начинать этому учиться) Спасибо, буду читать